# Ansible - disable ssh password authentication

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, openssh

I'm trying to make ansible task that handles `sshd_config` properly. I've found similar regexp from other questions but they do nothing.

```
name: Disable SSH password authentication
      become: true
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^#?\s*PasswordAuthentication\s'
        line: 'PasswordAuthentication no'
        state: present
```

Problem is it should handle duplicate lanes as well as comments. For example:

- There could be:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

or

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

or

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

or

```
PasswordAuthentication no
#PasswordAuthentication no
```

or

```
PasswordAuthentication no
# PasswordAuthentication no
```

or

```
# PasswordAuthentication no
# PasswordAuthentication no
```

etc so many combinations. But I just want to have single uncommented line `PasswordAuthentication no`

Is this possible?

Comment: To me this smells like a case of either **deploy the file in a desired state** or of, if customisations have to be undertaken, **use a jinja template to deploy the file in a desired state**.  Hacking away at individual lines rarely leads to an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Q: **"*handle duplicate lines as well as comments ... have single uncommented line `PasswordAuthentication no`*"**

A: Given the list of the files

```yaml
    my_files:
      - sshd_config.0
      - sshd_config.1
      - sshd_config.2
      - sshd_config.3
      - sshd_config.4
      - sshd_config.5
```

and the content

```sh
shell> for f in files-17/*; do printf "\n%s\n" $f; cat $f; done

files-17/sshd_config.0
PasswordAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes

files-17/sshd_config.1
PasswordAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no

files-17/sshd_config.2
PasswordAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes

files-17/sshd_config.3
PasswordAuthentication no
#PasswordAuthentication no

files-17/sshd_config.4
PasswordAuthentication no
# PasswordAuthentication no

files-17/sshd_config.5
# PasswordAuthentication no
# PasswordAuthentication no
```

The task below removes all but the first line which includes *`PasswordAuthentication`*

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: 'files-17/{{ item }}'
        after: 'PasswordAuthentication'
        regexp: '^(.*)PasswordAuthentication(.*)$'
        replace: ''
      loop: "{{ my_files }}"
```

gives

```sh
shell> for f in files-17/*; do printf "\n%s\n" $f; cat $f; done

files-17/sshd_config.0
PasswordAuthentication no


files-17/sshd_config.1
PasswordAuthentication no


files-17/sshd_config.2
PasswordAuthentication yes


files-17/sshd_config.3
PasswordAuthentication no


files-17/sshd_config.4
PasswordAuthentication no


files-17/sshd_config.5
# PasswordAuthentication no
```

The next task replaces the lines with *`PasswordAuthentication no`*

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: 'files-17/{{ item }}'
        regexp: '^(.*)PasswordAuthentication(.*)$'
        line: 'PasswordAuthentication no'
      loop: "{{ my_files }}"
```

gives

```
shell> for f in files-17/*; do printf "\n%s\n" $f; cat $f; done

files-17/sshd_config.0
PasswordAuthentication no


files-17/sshd_config.1
PasswordAuthentication no


files-17/sshd_config.2
PasswordAuthentication no


files-17/sshd_config.3
PasswordAuthentication no


files-17/sshd_config.4
PasswordAuthentication no


files-17/sshd_config.5
PasswordAuthentication no
```

The sequence of the tasks is idempotent.

Comment: I suggested this fix here, as I consider your solution much safer in the presence of duplicate entries: https://github.com/vitalk/ansible-secure-ssh/

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, it's not a general solution. Be careful! It will fail, for example, if "overriding settings on a per-user basis" is used. In this case, there may be multiple lines with the same parameters indented in separate blocks. To be on the save side use *template* instead. See [sshd.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/sshd.yml) on how to configure multiple parameters in a loop.

Comment: Good counter-example; it is not a general solution, and templates are reliable. But template solutions only work if ansible is the only source of modifications to ssh_config, which is true in most corporate ansible use-cases, but not true when you're using it as a more 'personal' tool, where you may be editing files by hand between ansible runs. I'd hate to clobber my per-user settings by either replace or template solution... everyone: be careful.

Answer (score 2):

If your distribution has a `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/` folder, you can just copy a file there:

```yaml
- name: Disallow SSH password authentication
  template: src=disablePasswordAuth.conf dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/disablePasswordAuth.conf
  notify:
    - restart sshd
```

Then also add `disablePasswordAuth.conf`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `ansible`

```yaml
  - name: Disallow SSH password authentication
    lineinfile:
      dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp="^PasswordAuthentication"
      line="PasswordAuthentication no"
      state=present
      validate: sshd -t -f %s
    notify:
      - restart sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ##-----------------------
  - name: Disallow SSH password authentication
    become: true
    block:
      - name: collect sshd configs
        ansible.builtin.find:
          paths: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d
          patterns: '*.conf'
          file_type: file
        register: collected_info

      - name: update sshd conf
        copy:
          dest: "{{ item.path }}"
          content: "PasswordAuthentication no\n"
        with_items: "{{ collected_info.files }}"
        register: update_result
      
      - name: restart sshd
        service:
          name: sshd
          state: restarted
        when: update_result.changed is true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Do the following:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add
```

And it won't ask for a password any more.